# When does OnUpgrade get called and how does it get the oldVersion parameter?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am working on an update for my current app. My app use SQLite DB and so far I am at version 1. I will need to alter/introduce new tables in my second version. I did my research and I found that to do that the best way is to have `switch`(`case`) statements in which I do the updates to db in a fall-through manner.

My question is, **how does android know what is the older version in the `onUpgrade()`?**. In fact, **when does it get called?**.

So for the users who are downloading my updated app for first time, I assume the `onUpgrade()` will not be called! **How would android know when not to call `onUpgrade()`?**

Please clarify this for me. I want to submit my first update and I don't want to lose my hard-earned users :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When implementing the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you pass a version parameter to the superclass constructor. This should be a static value you can change in future versions of your application (usually you'd want this to be a static final attribute of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation, alongside the database name you pass to the superclass constructor).

Then, when you want to update the database, you increment the version parameter that will be used in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation, and perform the SQL modifications you intend to do, programmatically, inside the `onUpgrade()` method.

Say your DB started with table A in version 1, then you added table B in version 2 and table C in version 3, your onUpgrade method would look like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) { // do stuff for migrating to version 2
        db.execSQL( ...create table B... );
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) { // do stuff for migrating to version 3
        db.execSQL( ...create table C... );
    }
}
```

When the superclass constructor runs, it compares the version of the stored SQLite .db file against the version you passed as a parameter. If they differ, `onUpgrade()` gets called.

I should check the implementation, but I assume `onUpgrade()` is also called after `onCreate()` if the database needs to be created, and there's a way to ensure all of the upgrades are executed (for example, by forcing all version numbers to be positive integers and initializing a newly created database with version 0).

Comment: Can you provide little more detailed explanation

Comment: This explanation really helped, maybe I can add that probably you can use your BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE as a parameter so that you don't have to track database versions manually, this way every new update will be guaranteed to have a new database version, in case you forget changing db version. Like so:                                                                                                        
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);

Comment: I think onCreate is called after onUpgrade ... on version change ...

Comment: Good answer. As pointed out by @barry-li onUpgrade is only called when an upgrade is needed and only by getReadableDatabase()/getWritableDatabase()

Answer (score 5):

`onUpgrade()` is NOT called from the constructor. The first time `getWritableDatabase()` is called, the database will be opened `onCreate()`, `onUpgrade()` and/or `onOpen()` will be called. That's why the constructor is on the main thread, but it's a better performance practice to call `getWritableDatabase()` from a worker thread.